# How does this recursive function with no parameters work?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

This function calculates the length of a singly linked list recursively.

`tail` is an instance variable that points to the next object in the list.

```java
    public int length() {
        if (tail == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 1 + tail.length();
    }
```

However it uses no parameters as shown. I'm struggling to understand the logic behind this code, could I get some help with understanding what's actually going on here?

My first point of confusion is when the function reaches the last object in the list, that objects tail will be null, so why does the function not just end up returning 1?
And secondly, what does `1 + tail.length()` actually do?

The most I understand is that `1` and `tail.length()` can be added due to the `length` function having a return type of int.

Comment: Please read the description of what you use as tags: DSA is ***not** Data Structures&Algorithms*. At that, presenting a definition/declaration of tha "data structure" might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have a list like `[a, b, c, d]` and you're calling `length()` on it. `this` will initially be the first element `a` and `tail` will be the next element `b`. So the flow of the code should be something like this:

```
this.length() // Element 'a'
Is tail == null? // No, tail is 'b'
return 1 + <result of length() of 'b'>
|
|   this.length() // Element 'b'
|   Is tail == null? // No, tail is 'c'
|   return 1 + <result of length() of 'c'>
|   |
|   |   this.length() // Element 'c'
|   |   Is tail == null? // No, tail is 'd'
|   |   return 1 + <result of length() of 'd'>
|   |   |
|   |   |   this.length() // Element 'd'
|   |   |   Is tail == null? // Yes, there's no element after 'd' so return 1
|   |   |   return 1 // return 1 from length() of 'd'
|   |   |
|   |   return 1 + 1 // return 2 from length() of 'c'
|   |
|   return 1 + 2 // return 3 from length() of 'b'
|
return 1 + 3 // return 4 from length() of 'a'
```

So in the end, `length()` will give you the correct result of `4`

Answer (score 1):

There is always 1 parameter to a member function ... the object you called the function on (represented by `this` in the function).

When you call

```
return 1 + tail.length();
```

The function `length` will have a `this` that refers to the `tail` here.  The `tail` in that function is `tail.tail`

Answer (score 1):

> when the function reaches the last object in the list, that objects tail will be null, so why does the function not just end up returning 1?

It does -- when called on the last object in the list.

> what does 1 + tail.length() actually do.

It calls `length` on the `tail` object.  When you say this has "no parameters," you're not quite right -- the parameter is which object it's being called on.  So if you call `node.length()` where `node.tail == tail1` and `tail1.tail == null`, then `node.length()` is `1 + tail1.length()` is `1 + 1` is 2, for a total length of 2 -- which is what we'd expect.

Comment: I see. this definitely helps a lot however there's still one thing I want to clarify. why does 1 + tail.length() == 1 + 1? that's whats stumping me.

Comment: `tail.length()` is 1, since it's the last element of the list.  So `1 + tail.length()` is `1 + 1`.